# Is there a program that automatically e-mails new files?

Tags: software-rec, email, file-sharing

I work in a lab where many of the (Windows) computers are fairly stand-alone and single-purpose, attached to various lab equipment (spectrophotometers, etc), and connected to the network principally to let people e-mail themselves/post on Google docs whatever results they need.

Is there some script/program that could do something like this automatically?  I was thinking about making a little one that would just look for some magic file or magic name containing some address that would tell it where to e-mail new things it sees.

Using shared Dropbox folder, Google Docs collection, etc. seems a little onerous as one would have to manually add other users to it (assuming they even had an account).  This would be used by non-computery people as well, who may be scared of a black window with monospaced text.

Comment: what os are you using?

Comment: Windows; the software of science (the most highly supported one by scientific equipment manufacturers) :P

Answer (score 1):

Not quite as comprehensive as i'd like but this should get you started.

If you're using windows, something like [blat](http://www.blat.net/) would do part of what you need, combined with something that'll detect changes.Offhand i think [belvedere](http://lifehacker.com/341950/belvedere-automates-your-self+cleaning-pc) might do the trick, but i can't check that bit at the moment. If you can code, you could throw something together like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261%28VS.85%29.aspx) to handle that bit, alternatively

For linux, you can use mutt for sending the mail (something like echo “body text” | mutt -a attachedfile.ext -s “title” email@foo.com sends an attachment ...) and you can probably use inotify - maybe with a script utilising [inotify](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/) tools for detection of changes.

Comment: Does *blat* fire off an email without needing some account to send it with?